# javascript formatting on cshtml pages - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, razor

My Visual Studio has given up autoformatting/indent javascript on a cshtml page when there is a "@" somewhere in the javascript

This can't autoformat

```
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 10,
        "ajax": {
            url: "@Url.Action("CustomServerSideSearchAction", "Home")",
            type: 'POST'
        }
    });
```

But this works fine

```
    var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 10,
        "ajax": {
            url: "Url.Action("CustomServerSideSearchAction", "Home")", //@ remove - now it dont work but can autoformat
            type: 'POST'
        }
    });
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4.2(up to date)

Do anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: still at version Win64 16.7.5